# Launch configuration DocsConnectionPropsHelper references class from closed project

Tags: eclipse, class

As the title says, eclipse gives me this error:

Launch configuration DocsConnectionPropsHelper references class from closed project foo

So my question is how can I find which class is the one that depends on the closed project and delete it.

How can  I find that class? Even with closed the other project my project has no errors or anything.